# Each GROUP BY expression must contain columns that are not outer references

Tags: mysql, sql

Have been messing with this for a while now, but can't seem to get closer to it working.

Project `InvoiceNbr`, `InvoiceDt` and `TotalPrice` for all invoices where the `TotalPrice` is greater than the average `TotalPrice`. Sort on `InvoiceNbr` descending.

This is what I have come up with:

```
SELECT  I.InvoiceNbr AS Invoice#,
        I.InvoiceDt AS Date,
        I.TotalPrice AS Amount
FROM INVOICE AS I 
WHERE I.TotalPrice IN
    (SELECT AVG(I.TotalPrice)
    FROM INVOICE
    GROUP BY I.InvoiceDt, I.InvoiceNbr, TotalPrice
    HAVING I.TotalPrice > AVG(I.TotalPrice));
GO
```

Keep getting the error:

> Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result. (As formatted text, not images.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are off on the logic.  You want to return the average, either using a `join` in the `from` or a subquery.  You've started with the subquery, so let's go down that route:

```
SELECT  I.InvoiceNbr AS Invoice#,
        I.InvoiceDt AS Date,
        I.TotalPrice AS Amount
FROM INVOICE I
WHERE I.TotalPrice > (SELECT AVG(I2.TotalPrice)
                      FROM INVOICE I2
                     );
```